# How to start and stop an Amazon EC2 instance based on traffic

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Is there an easy way to start an Amazon instance when someone visits the web app and stop if the web app remains idle for a specified amount of time?

Comment: It's conceivably possible (probably involving a static starter page on S3 and Lambda functions behind an API gateway to spin up instances...), but "easy" is not how I'd describe it.

Comment: @MortyAndFam this is one of the reasons people are enthusiastic about [serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/) computing.  You're proposing something unweildy and impractical and unlikely to result in the desired outcome, since the Internet is full of random noise that would likely keep your server awake much more often than you probably assume.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot agree, in my experience you'll get about a request a minute

Answer (score 2):

It's probably possible, but it's unlikely to be practical. It takes at least 30 seconds and maybe as much as 3 minutes to start an instance, most browsers time out after 30 seconds. Most humans give up on a website if it takes more than 6 - 10 seconds to load. So unless you have a special case I doubt your approach will work.

In most cases [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) is a much better choice for what I think you probably need. You don't run a server, but it can be set up so when someone visits your website it will run some code and deliver them a web page (or json / etc). You probably can't in practice run Wordpress on it, but you can run a [serverless blog](https://serverlessblog.com/).

A static website would be better hosted on [S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html). Sometimes rendering a website to static is practical, if you don't need it to be interactive.